# Android: what are the default ids of views?

Tags: android, view

I ask this because I have exceptions from reports (from users from the market), mentioning that I have duplicated views with id 0x2 (or 0x3).

Since all my generated ids are really big, I think that the views with duplicated ids are views with no specifically defined ids.

My question is what are the ids of the views, that the developer hasn't explicitly assigned ids to them.

Thanks in advance,
Danail

Comment: As I said in my answer: According to the source code, a View for which you haven't set an ID, has an ID of -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AAPT constantly updates your R file to generate unique hexadecimal values for each of your own IDs. In terms of IDs YOU create, they only need to be unique within the parent viewgroup. As always please post your stacktrace.

According to the source code, a View for which you haven't set an ID, has an ID of -1.

```
public static final int NO_ID = -1;
```

Comment: My question is for views, that don't have ids assigned.

Comment: I don't have any ids that are with such small ids like 0x2 or 0x3 (when generated, they are with really big numbers). I don't think the exception is relevant here, just want to know what are the default ids assigned to views when no id is explicitly defined for them.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no id is created if you do not specify an id to a view. Try creating a very simple application and create components with no id's , you'll notice that no id's are created in the R.java file.